# Can't access Google Apps (Play Store, Youtube, Drive etc) on Data

Tags: google-play-store, mobile-data, youtube, asus-zenfone-2

Asus Zenfone 2 Ze550ml, Lollipop 5.0, Non-Rooted, AT&T 3G

The Play Store, Youtube and Drive(which won't sync on data) Apps work perfectly on Wifi but not on Data (It shows a message saying Check your connection and try again). Maps works on Data though.

It used to work on data I remember at some point but I must've turned on restrict background data at some point, but I have since turned it off in Data Usage.
I've tried the 4 years in the future time trick, clear cache and data of google playstore, framwork and services trick, removing all google accounts from the phone one, my hosts file in etc has just one line Localhost 127.0.0.1 , all to no avail.

Anyone with any other suggestions on how I can get back use of these apps on data?